# Where to find system.info in MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am installing a php website on server, but I am getting the following error and I am really not sure how to fix that. where can I find/edit this system_info file what does it actually mean.

My databse just has thedomain_db2, how do I get rid of this error.

> Database error: Invalid SQL: select * from system_info; MySQL Error :
>   Table 'thedomain_db2.system_info' doesn't exist

UPDATE:
THESE are the erros I get while running Install.php

> Warning: require_once(./install/init.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/thedomain/public_html/user12/scripts/old_install/install_cls.php on line 27
>
> Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required './install/init.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/thedomain/public_html/user12/scripts/old_install/install_cls.php on line 27

Comment: Did you create the `system_info` table?

Comment: No it was supposed to be there. I mean database was supposed to be there. there was no need to create it because I am not sure what are all the fields as this is  a turnkey website

Comment: the error message clearly states that the table does not exist in the database you are connecting to. Is there another database on the same MySQL server?

Comment: @Jocelyn: I just updated my question.

Comment: Did you rename `install` to `old_install`?  You are supposed to rename the folder *AFTER* running installer.  Rename `old_install` back to `install`.

Comment: @Rocket: Buddy I dont know how to thank you. It worked me for now. Thanks a Million.I am over the moon. God Bless you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are missing a table(system_info), which is required by the software application you are installing, in your database. If the software you are installing doesn't have a setup file or something like that, you'll have to manually make this table.
I can't tell you how to do that though, it depends on the application's needs. (Maybe it would help if you mentioned the name of the software you are trying to install.)

Comment: The setup is there inside install folder. but when I uploaded the site. It asked me to delete or rename the install folder. I renamed it.

Comment: @Mike: Did you actually run the setup?  It asks you to delete (or rename) it for security reasons, so other people can't run it.

Comment: @Mike: it certainly asked to delete or rename the install folder AFTER running the install script of your software. This ensures nobody will run the install script again and erase or overwrite all or part of your database.